# problem install start.sh file for portal

Tags: debian, terminal

i'm stil new to all this and i know how to install it properly but every time i run the `./start.sh` or the `sudo sh start.sh` it gives me this:

`./start.sh /home/danielblain156/Desktop/Portal_Linux/Portal/game/hl2.sh: line 69: /home/danielblain156/Desktop/Portal_Linux/Portal/game/hl2_linux: No such file or directory`
and i can't seem to fix it if you have any idea as to how i can go about installing this please let me know i would love to get to play this game.

Comment: The `start.sh` script expects a file `hl2_linux` to exist in a certain subdirectory under your Desktop directory, but it's not there. That's all that can be said, based on your description. You need to provide context, in particular what it is that you want to install, and what you have done before launching the start script. It may also be helpful to provide a pointer to the installation instructions.

Comment: i'm trying to install portal onto my chromebook and i downloaded it from https://freelinuxpcgames.com/portal/  and then try'd following it;s installation instructions.

Comment: the only advice we can have with this elements is that you should learn some shell basics

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing 32bit libs, and your system is 64bit. If you are using Ubuntu you can do the following. First, confirm if this is the case.

```
file file-name
```

above will show an output like this

```
file-name: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
```

also, the file you have to do this is in game dir hl2_linux. don't do it on the start.sh file. then run the following commands.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
./file-name
```

if you are not using an ubuntu or Debian-based distro try installing Steam.